# Tkinter delete methode

Tags: tkinter, python-3.9

I'm using Tkinter, I defined the function below to clear entries but it only works for the entries that have default values even when I input new values in these entries it can delete them but it does not clear the entry that doesn't have default values, Where is the problem, Why entry4 doesn't get clear?

```
def clear_text():
    entry1.delete(0, END)
    entry2.delete(0, END)
    entry3.delete(0, END)
    if entry4:
        entry4.delete(0, END)

entry1 = ttk.Entry(left_frame,textvariable=text1)
entry1.insert(0,'1.5')
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=10, padx=0, pady=10)

entry2 = ttk.Entry(left_frame,textvariable=text2)
entry2.insert(0,'2')
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=10, padx=0, pady=10)

entry3 = ttk.Entry(left_frame,textvariable=text3)
entry3.grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=10, padx=0, pady=10)
entry3.insert(0,'100')

entry4 = ttk.Entry(left_frame, textvariable=text4).grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx=10, padx=0, pady=10)

delete_button = ttk.Button(left_frame, text = "Delete", command=clear_text)
delete_button.grid(row=9, column=0, ipadx=10, padx=0, pady=10)
```

This is what will happen after I click the Delete button
[image: First image]

[image]

Comment: It is obviously that `entry4` is `None`.

Comment: The first and most important problem is your script. Please do me a favor and copy just the code you've posted and try to run and please tell me what happend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line -

```
entry4 = ttk.Entry(left_frame, textvariable=text4).grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx=10, padx=0, pady=10)
```

is the problem.

When you define a Tkinter object, it is better to separate the `.pack` or `.grid` so that the variable `entry4` refers to the tkinter entry object rather than the `.grid` method which is a nonetype.

Try this -

```
entry4 = ttk.Entry(left_frame, textvariable=text4)
entry4.grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx=10, padx=0, pady=10)
```